# rake db commands not working on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, production-environment

I've just set up my production server with a postgres db, change the env to production and run `bundle install --deployment`. I have also set up the postgres user on my server and created the necessary db.

When I run `rake db:schema:load` I get the following error:

```
$ rake db:schema:load
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "Javu"
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:646:in `connection'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:661:in `block in method_missing'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/home/rails/db/schema.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/schema.rb:41:in `instance_eval'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/schema.rb:41:in `define'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/schema.rb:61:in `define'
/home/rails/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:218:in `load_schema_for'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:235:in `block in load_schema_current'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:234:in `load_schema_current'
/home/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:244:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`rake db:migrate`, `rake db:create` and `rake db:drop` returned similar errors.

My `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
default: &default     
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
development: 
  <<: *default
  database: example_developement
  password: ~
  user: Javu
production: 
  <<: *default
  database: example_production
  user: postgres
  host: localhost
test: 
  database: example_test
```

What do I have to do to fix this error and make the schema load work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your database isn't configure to let your user access it. Take Rails out of the equation and using `psql` try to connect to the database using the information in your database.yml file.  So something like...

```
psql -h localhost -U example_production
```

Get that working. Then Rails should be okay. You may need to tweak PostgreSQL or your database.yml so they agree on user/password/host settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error returned suggests that you're trying to log in with the wrong user, the issue here seems to be that you aren't setting the Rails environment correctly.

Try running the command like this `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:load`.